# How to replicate tables from Oracle to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, replication

We have an Oracle server in sister-company that is a bottleneck for our SQL Server-based business process. When we use SSIS to query all tables we need, it completes in 5 hours (millions of records, but very few changes). Business wants data refresh slightly faster.

How to replicate the data from Oracle to SQL Server in easy way with no third party tools?

No admin rights in Oracle for us (only reading data and listing tables/views), but we've got sysadmin in SQL Server (2014 Enterprise).

Answer (score 1):

Set up a linked server.  pull the tables using a proc.  Not guaranteed to be faster.  Also, have you tried tuning the SSIS package?  Set accurate values for commit sizes, maxed out the buffer settings.  Tried bulk-data-distributor, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the batch size property. I always try 10000 rows but you should experiment. Many users have seen 10-50% improvement. You can also buy an  Attunity Connector which can also improve performance considerably.

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle to SQL Server => I would consider using sqlplus to offload data into CSV or delimited format and bcp'ing it into SQL*Server.

Answer (score 0):

We have used [SQL Server Migration Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/sql-server-migration-assistant?view=sql-server-ver15) which was quite efficient.

For the long term, you could consider SSIS to incrementally load your staging database in SQL Server.